# Simple static IP problem

Tags: static-ip

I have an ethernet device which has the following requirements:

- persistent ip configuration
- uses ports: 50000 to 50003

I can set up a static ip4 connection with nm-connection-editor, but I don't know how to set the following parameters:

Connection:

- Address
- Netmask
- Gateway
- (DNS)

Camera:

- Address
- Subnet mask

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i think these values depend on the ISP (internet service provider)
an example-
address- 192.168.1.13
netmask- 255.255.255.0
gateway- 192.168.1.1

maybe they work for you

Comment: Its and embedded system, and I have only one port, so I have no internet and device connected at the same time.